# When a user is deleted, OP highlighting is lost

Tags: discussion, bug, status-declined, deleted-accounts, highlighting

Deleted:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Not Deleted:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: I don't see much point in highlighting an unreal username though.

Comment: @Ϻ.Λ.Ʀ. Show it was OP, as they normally do. Indicate self answer etc. It's not to show off a username, it's to indicate those things.

Comment: Arguably, those things shouldn't really matter.

Comment: Fix: request the post to be attributed to you ;) (done that, works)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a user is deleted, we also remove their identifier from the posts - what you see at this point is just the generated user name left over from their deletion.

The actual link between the post and the OP is lost.

And since user names are not unique, it is not a field we can use to identify the OP (it is also a text field, and doing that in the database would be very expensive).

Comment: If the case is the post being deleted, not migrated, than the generated user name is `user{id}`. Since the id is unique, it's possible to identify the posts by the same user.

Comment: Or you just don't want the inconsistency, then it's fair.

Answer (score 3):

Since SE has declined to fix this, I've written a user script replacement for this feature.  It's already in the development branch of my [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) user script, and will be part of the next stable release (v1.42) soon.

The actual implementation is fairly simple:

```js
var name = $('.question .post-signature.owner .user-details').not(':has(a)').text().trim();
if ( name === "" ) return;

$('span.comment-user:not(.owner)').filter( function () {
    return this.textContent === name;
} ).addClass('owner');
```

The first two lines check whether the question author is a non-existent user (as indicated by the fact that there's no link to their user profile), and if so, extracts their username.  The rest of the code then adds the class `owner` to any comments written by non-existent users with the same name.

(The full code in SOUP is slightly more complicated, to take care of edge cases like new posts and comments loaded via Ajax, dupe review pages with multiple questions included on a single page, and styling the highlighted usernames with appropriate padding.  Fortunately, there's existing code in SOUP to make all that fairly easy.)

As [noted by Oded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268646), basing the highlighting on the username introduces an unavoidable potential for ambiguity: if another nonexistent user with the exact same name as the OP comments on the same thread, there's no way to tell the two users' comments apart.  In practice, this is not a common occurrence (indeed, I've yet to find any examples of it), but it *could* happen.  The *user12345* style usernames generated by user deletion should be fairly unique, since they're based on user IDs.  A more likely cause for such confusion are migrated posts, where comments by users that don't have an account on the target site are identified only by their username on the source site.

Here's a screenshot from [a migrated question with comments](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2544/is-wieners-attack-on-rsa-extendable-to-larger-keys-with-low-hamming-weight) demonstrating this feature:

> [image: Screenshot]